# A realistic educational software for simulating electronic circuits in linux

Tags: linux, educational

Is there any High-School level software for Linux which can simulate simple electronic circuits, (e.g. flip-flop circuit), and run them?

Kicad is not an easy to learn software and cannot be used for educational purposes.

Comment: Should it be free (both meanings)?

Comment: I prefer a free software in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you mean digital simulation [Logisim](http://www.cburch.com/logisim/) seems to meet your requirements (donno about the "easy to learn" aspect, tho - that's open to interpretation)

Comment: It is not realistic. For example there are no batteries or lamps available.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus Then you should have written a better question (more requirements). That helps you get the answers you want. You can still edit it, and add your comment answer to Adrian as well.

Comment: Hm, quite a leap from batteries and bulbs to flipflop simulations. I doubt you'll find a single tool covering them both at a simple-enough level (you could do it with SPICE-like tools, but that's fairly advanced). For realy basic subjects you can find per-subject simulators, like these ones: http://www.physicsclassroom.com/Physics-Interactives/Electric-Circuits/Circuit-Builder/Circuit-Builder-Interactive  http://jersey.uoregon.edu/vlab/Voltage/ Google's your friend: https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl#q=battery+bulb+simulator.

Comment: Well,  physicsclassroom.com/Physics-Interactives/Electric-Circuits/ is good. But I'm looking for something more than just batteries and lamps. Somehing which includes resisters, capacitors, diodes, transisters and probably speakers too. including voltmeter and amperemeters. And by realistic I mean the lamps will turn on like a real experiment. Logisim is too pure and I don't think a beginner will understand it.